# LaTeX macro/command to turn BibTeX entry into a custom key

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'd like to define a command such as `\paperkey{bibitem}`, where if `bibitem` contains a BibTeX entry for a paper such as

> Foo A, Bar B, Some Title, 2004

It generates `FB04` as output.

In other words, I'd like to generate text from the first letter of each author's last name sequentially, followed by a 2-letter year. Bonus points if the command/macro can replace additional authors above 4 with a `+`: `CJKW+10`.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you use `biblatex`? If so, this should be easily possible. What bibliography package do you use? What bibliography style do you use? You can show us an MWE/MWEB of what you have so far, then it is easier for us to test our solution with your setup.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple in `biblatex` (using the `labelalpha` option).

All one has to do is to declare a template to build the label. Specifically, a template to build the label using the name and year, and the specifying how to parse the names (using the `\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate`). The final step is to create a special cite command for `\paperkey`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelalpha=true,minalphanames=3,maxalphanames=3]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left,names={1-3+}]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
  }
}

\DeclareLabelalphaNameTemplate{
   \namepart[strwidth=1]{family}
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\paperkey}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelalpha}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\paperkey{herrmann}

\paperkey{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]